# Static footer is overlapped by input panel

Tags: android

I am trying to create a screen where you have a `ScrollView` on top and under that you have a `TextView` and a `Button`.

The `ScrollView` contains a `TableLayout` which it self contains `TextView`'s, `Button`'s and `EditText`'s.

What I would like to achieve is that when a `EditText` is focues and the input panel opens on the phone,  the buttom footer would be moved on top of the panel and the scroll area resized smaller, so that you can click the calculate button at any moment.

Here is my current xml:

The activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <include layout="@layout/activity_germinative_scroll"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCalculationResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0.00 KG/HA"
            android:textSize="35sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculateGerminative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:text="@string/calculate_germinative"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button_states"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/editSeedMass"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Scroll activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="beginning|end"
    >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/teraMass"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".40"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="@string/seed_mass_text"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

            <Space
                android:layout_width="13dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/seedMassInfo"
                android:tag="seedMassInfo"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/info"/>
        </TableRow>

        <Space
            android:layout_height="3dp"/>

        ... Many other TableRow's with the exact same layout...


    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So what happens right now is that when I focus on one of the input fields in my scroll area,  the button at the bottom gets resized into a very thin little button and depending of the screen size, the text-field in the footer will get resized also.

I use this setting for the activity in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

Is the problem because of the overall layout I use or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set fixed height for the Button `calculateGerminative` and TextView `textViewCalculationResult`, and set the scrollview height to dynamic, i.e.

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: But if I set fixed heights for them, then I have to set different heights for every different screen size?

Comment: You should use dp "A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way."  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms, **dp** scales across different dpi